# Set new woocommerce subtotal and apply a coupon to a new subtotal

Tags: php, woocommerce, discount

I'm creating a new discount rule to cart subtotal as below, but then the coupon applied doesn't get applied to the new subtotal.

How to set new subtotal in cart and apply coupon to the new subtotal?

```
$subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
if (($subtotal > 2399)&&($subtotal <= 3200))
{
    $eligible = ((15/100)*$subtotal);
}
else if (($subtotal > 3200)&&($subtotal <= 3500))
{
    $eligible = ((18/100)*$subtotal);
}
else if (($subtotal > 3500)&&($subtotal < 3500))
{
    $eligible = ((20/100)*$subtotal);
}       
$newsubtotal = $subtotal - $eligible;

if ( $amount = WC()->cart->get_coupon_discount_amount( $coupon->code, WC()->cart->display_cart_ex_tax ) ) 
{

    //i need to get discount amount based on new subtotal
    $discount_html = '-' . wc_price( $amount );
} 
else 
{
    $discount_html = '';
}
```

Comment: I'm adding this code in a template cart total

Comment: This is not logic and making real big complications with coupons. so if you change the subtotal this will make multiple discounts and all other totals will be wrong… You should better try to add this conditional rules for line items in `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`, or using a negative cart fee (a discount) in `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`… There is many working examples in stackOverFlow